# Hadoop on Mac in intelliJ IDEA setup

Tags: macos, hadoop, intellij-idea, mapreduce

Installed hadoop using brew, now want to run hadoop jobs in intelliJ IDEA. How to setup the environment and resolve dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

After spending lot's of time, was finally able to run hadoop jobs from intelliJ IDEA. Hope this might save time for others.

```
brew upgrade hadoop
```

installed/updated hadoop in **/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.x.x**
Now, we will try to import dependency from this location in our intelliJ

1. Launch IntelliJ and click on ‘**Create New Project**’
2. Create a **java project**
3. Go to **File** -> **Project Structure** -> Select **Project Module** in Modules -> Select **Dependencies Tab** -> Select **‘+’** in bottom and click **Jars or Directories** -> Import
   dependencies from Hadoop installation

[image]

5. For importing dependencies, first select all folders inside ..**/hadoop-
   2.x.x/share/hadoop/**

[image]

Repeat Step 4 and import **../Hadoop-2.x.x/share/hadoop/common/lib** folder

[image]

Hadoop environment is integrated with intelliJ Java Project. You can create new java classes to implement your drivers, mappers, reducers etc.

Comment: You should really use Maven/Gradle instead of adding the JAR files manually

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 , could you please provide step by step process do so. I am not an expert in Maven/Gradle based IDEs

Comment: Too broad for Stackoverflow, sorry. Main point - you can use any or no IDE which is useful to build your code within an actual Hadoop  cluster